# Multiple column count and aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have following table which has multiple entries for an order and the order can either be rejected or approved.

---

```
Amount  | Approved | Rejected | OrderNo 
-------------------------------------------
 10     |   N      |    Y     |   10
 20     |   Y      |    N     |   10
 30     |   N      |    N     |   10
 40     |   Y      |    N     |   10
 22     |   N      |    Y     |   11
 10     |   N      |    N     |   10
--------------------------------------------
```

Want to build a result set which can summarise.

```
OrderNo | TotalEntries | Approved_Or_Rejected_Entries | TotalAmount
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  10    |   5          |           3                  |    110
  11    |   1          |           1                  |     22
```

Comment: What happens if you end up with a Y in *both* approved and rejected?

Comment: @EricBrandt I didn't see it will correct

Comment: @MatBailie that shouldn't happen since on updating Approved will mark rejected as N and vice versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    orderno,
    count(*) totalentries
    sum(case when 'Y' in (approved, rejected) then 1 else 0 end) approved_or_rejected
    sum(amount) total_amount
from mytable
group by orderno
```

Comment: To MatBailie's point above, it might be necessary to add together two case expressions, one for the `approved` column and one for the `rejected` column, then sum that result. But the OP can sort that out. +1 for speed.